# how i can create selected_index_changed event of combobox in datagridview

Tags: vb.net

my datagridview name is "DG" and i add combobox column programatically named item as shown in code below.i want to create the event which call on itemchanged of combobox.i use DG_CellLeave event but it not call after the item selection immediatly but call when we leave the cell.i want to create event which immediatly call on selection change event of combobox.

```
    Dim item As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
    item.DataSource = dset.Tables("tab")
    item.HeaderText = "item"
    item.Name = "item"
    item.DisplayMember = "p_name"
    item.DataPropertyName = "item"
    DG.Columns.Add(item)
```

which event should i choose for this purpose...

Comment: You can use `Private Sub DataGridView1_CellValueChanged(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellValueChanged`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look at: [DataGridView.EditingControlShowing Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.editingcontrolshowing?view=netframework-4.7.2). This event is raised whenever an edit control is shown in the `DataGridView`. It can be handled/used like below:

```
Dim gridComboBox As ComboBox

Private Sub DG_EditControlShowing(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewEditingControlShowingEventArgs)
    ' Check to see if the ColumnIndex is where we expect to have the DropDown
    If (DG.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex = 1) Then
        ' Get the ComboBox that is being shown
        gridComboBox = TryCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
        If Not (gridComboBox Is Nothing) Then
            ' Always remove the Event Handler before Adding, when setting them at runtime
            RemoveHandler gridComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf gridComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged
            AddHandler gridComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf gridComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub gridComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim dropDown As ComboBox = TryCast(sender, ComboBox)
    if not(dropDown is nothing) then
        Dim drv as DataRowView =  dropDown.SelectedItem
        if Not (drv is nothing) then
           Debug.Print(drv("item"))
        end if
    end if
End Sub
```

The `SelectedIndexChanged` event is raised as per a ComboBox used outside of a DataGridView.